# Did people sat on mats in the bible era or mainly on chairs?

Tags: cultural-analysis

Did people sit on mats in the bible era (like some Arabic cultures nowadays) or they sat mainly on chairs?

Comment: Hi Ubiquitous Student, welcome to BH.SE - thanks for contributing! Please do take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) or check the Help Center to learn more about the site's context and what kind of questions to ask here. I've closed the question as it stands as off-topic. In a nutshell - in hermeneutics we always 'start from the text' and deal with questions that naturally arise from it. If it's not a question about a text, it's probably off-topic.

Comment: Maybe a question for history.stackexchange.com

Comment: They also had beds or sofas.

Comment: @SteveTaylor, sorry, I wasn't aware of it. Anyway, I have a good point to start from a text: proverbs 31:22, according to some translations "She has made *a carpet for herself* and a robe of fine white linen and of purple". https://biblehub.com/proverbs/31-22.htm

Comment: @PerryWebb Thank you for your advice. I've taken it. https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/65679/did-people-sit-on-mats-in-the-bible-era-or-mainly-on-chairs?noredirect=1#comment208970_65679

Comment: That's a great idea - if you update the question to focus on that text and ask about what that word means in context, that would be on-topic and we could get that reopened for you pretty fast.